# Excel Conditional Formatting if one column is equal to another

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

This should be the simplest example of conditional formatting but I can't figure it out.

I have two columns seperated by several dozen other columns (`C`-original data, `BO`- calculated value) and I need to highlight the calculated value if it is not equal to the original value.

I can do this on a cell by cell basis but can't see how to apply it to a whole column without adding a rule for every row (there are many 1000s of rows).

What am I missing?

Comment: You want to highlight values which are unequal to each other or those which are equal to each other? Your title and question body seem to be contradicting :S

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tend to use an IF() rule for this sort of thing. The trick is then to get the '$' signs right. If column C is the original data and BO is the calculated value, then select the BO column and add a conditional formatting *formula* rule of:

```
=IF($C2=$BO2,1,0)
```

Note there is no $ sign beside the row number, which causes it to apply to each row in turn.

Answer (score 7):

Select column BO and use the following:

```
=$C2<>$BO2
```

Comment: Please be aware you have posted an answer to an old question that already has an accepted answer. This means your answer will not likely get any attention, nor be accepted.

Comment: It is a better answer than the officially accepted one, though.